# PHP converting URL string to ASCII characters

Tags: php, html, forms, ascii

I have a string of Characters that is passed in a URL.

The string happens to contain a group of characters that is equivalent to an ASCII code.

When I try to use the string on the page using the `$_GET` command, it converts the part of the string that is equivalent to the ASCII code to the ASCII code instead of passing the actual string.

For example the URL contains a string  `Name='%bert%'`.  But when I echo out `$_GET['Name']` I get `'3/4rt%'` instead of `'%bert%'`.  How can I get the actual text?

Answer (score 0):

You're not escaping your data properly.

If you want to use `%bert%` in a URL, you need to encode your `%` as `%25`, making your query string value `%25bert%25`.

`%` in a URL means that the next two characters are going to be some encoded entity, so if you want to use it literally, it must be encoded this way.

You can read more information here:  http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Answer (score 0):

try passing `Name='%25bert%25'` instead of Name='%bert%'.

Note: %25 acts as escape character for % is url query string!